# JSON with text and image

Tags: android, ios, json, post

I need to upload to a server information about users, including an avatar. So far it works fine and I used FTP transfer to upload the image, means the JSON has only the text information of the user.

But I want to combine both in one JSON. Something like this:

```
{
    name: 'Jason Manson',
    age: 45,
    gender: 0,
    avatar: [IMG element]
}
```

Is this possible to do? If yes, how to use it in Xcode, Android and with php? Any sample available.

This is for both, send from app to server and get back from server to app.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use a multipart system of uploading images with Json, You can use the below method to upload single or multiple images with JSON(Text) to server...!
mImagePath is the arraylist of image paths

```
// Method for sending files using multiparting......
public static String sendJsonWithFile(Activity mActivity, ArrayList<String> mImagePaths, String jsonString, String URL)
{
    Log.e("json", jsonString);
    String res = "";
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        boundary = "--" + boundary;
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    StringBody stringBody = new StringBody(jsonString);

    reqEntity.addPart("formstring", stringBody);

    for (int i = 0; i < mImagePaths.size(); i++)
    {
        String imagePath = mImagePaths.get(i);
        if (mImagePaths != null && mImagePaths.size() > 0)
        {

            byte[] filebytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imagePath));

            ByteArrayBody filebodyImage = new ByteArrayBody(filebytes, "image");
            Log.e("file path=", filebodyImage.toString());

            reqEntity.addPart("image", filebodyImage);

        }

    }

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        res = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    res = "UnsupportedEncodingException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e)
{
    res = "ClientProtocolException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    res = "FileNotFoundException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    res = "IOException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    res = "Exception";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return res;
}
```